# Matplotlib - How to add multiple lines text box on the left y axis within a figure

Tags: matplotlib

I need to add Multiple lines text on the left y axis within a figure, I try legend and figtext() but it can not work well for me.

for example

```
a = 123   ----------------------
b = 456   ----------------------   
...       ----------------------
...       ----------------------
z = 789   ----------------------
```

the dash lines is my axes, axes is bigger than textbox

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4],'ro-')

plt.text(0.5,2,'$a=3$\n$b=2$',fontsize=32)

plt.show()
```

Also look up `annotate` which in some cases is easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the text is not fully appear on my canvas and totally disappear when I maximize the window

Comment: @billyduc: Yeah, by default `matplotlib` assumes that all the relevant info of the plot is contained *within* the axes area. You need to change the size of the axes with respect to the canvas--- either programmatically, or manually using sliders at the bottom of the figure window

Comment: can you look at this link http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html this is what I really want, I want one text box on the left and 2 different size subplots on the right

Comment: I can't see any text boxes in that example. Can you show a minimal complete example of what you've tried so far and which demonstrates the problem?